# error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays

Help, i can't delete the last row in my table. There's no error when i am deleting the other records but then the last 1, i cannot delete it

here's my code:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int row = table1.getSelectedRow();
    if(row >= 0){
    int opt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Confirm to Delete?", "Delete", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(opt==0){
    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/finals?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL", "root", "");
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table1.getModel();
    model.removeRow(row);
    String value = (table1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
    String query = "DELETE FROM student WHERE id_num = '"+ value + "'";
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    pst.executeUpdate(query);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Deleted Successfully. \nYour record has been updated.", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
    }
    else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please select a record.", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the Exception is being thrown in the line `String value = ...` by the `getValueAt(row, 0)` expression.

If that is the case, I guess you need to switch these 2 lines:

```
model.removeRow(row);
String value = (table1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
```

if you remove the last row, your table model is empty. That's why `getValueAt(row, 0)` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @ZachMendes you can upvote and/or accept this answer, thanks :)